# Using an array to filter through an array

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I have an array of chars (data[]) and I need to filter out only those whose index is a prime number. The array of chars (data[]) can contain up to 1000*1000*3 elements. Now, I get a list of prime numbers from 2 to 1000*1000*3 from a function and store it in a globally defined array (primes[]). How can I use it to filter out the data[] array? This is my code so far:

```
int k = 0;
char filtered[] = {0}; // I don't know what to put between the [ ] brackets.
for(int i = 0; i < ???; i++) // what do I put instead of ???
{
    filtered[i] = data[primes[k]];
    k++
}

for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    printf("%c\n", filtered[i]);
```

But this code obviously gives me SIGSEGV. Could you please help me fixing this?

Comment: Sounds like an AB problem to me. What are you trying to implement exactly? The sieve of eratosthenes?

Comment: @harper It is obviously pseudo-code.

Comment: If you want to only copy those elements having a prime number as index, your upper limit should be the length of the `primes` array, ie. the number of prime numbers less than 3000000. The easy way would be counting the prime numbers while you fill the `primes` array. An approximation of that number can be made using the Prime Number Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).

Comment: just replace the **k** variable with **i** in your array plus stop using that **???** thing

Comment: I put in ??? because I didn't know what to put there, that's why there's a comment clarifying that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you created `primes` did you know the size?  If so, then use it.  Otherwise, you should probably compute the primes yourself so you know how many there are.

Also, there is no need for the variable `k` in your code.  The loop can be shortened to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ???; i++) // what do I put instead of ???
{
   filtered[i] = data[primes[i]];
}
```

Comment: This is how I defined primes: `unsigned long primes[1000*1000*3];`

Comment: And how do you fill the array?  Do you know how many entries were added to primes when it was created?  If so, use that value.  Also, what comes after the last prime in `primes`?  If it is `-1` or something, then use `1000*1000*3` as your loop bounds, and add another check to stop if `primes[i]<0`.

Comment: I use a loop `for(int i = 2; i <= limit; i++)` where limit is 1000*1000*3. That fills up primes[]. I didn't add anything at the end of the array.

Comment: What is primes filled with?  Perhaps if you posted the full code, we'd have a better chance of helping you.

Comment: I go through a bit array and find bits of the value 0, in which case I assign its index to primes[k]. So, prime indexes of bits, which give me the list of all primes from 2 to 3*1000*1000.

Comment: Now, when I print all the primes from 2 to 3*1000*1000, I get a list of all of them followed by a large series of zeroes. When I wc'd it, it says to have 3 000 000 lines.

Comment: Is the function that fills the primes your code?  If so, why haven't you posted it?  Otherwise, use 3000000 as your loop value, but break if `primes[i]<=0`.

Comment: Because it would be difficult to post it here. The function is dependent on two header files and one c file. I only have it working because I linked it through a Makefile

Comment: Then I cannot help you further.